# How to use my own validation data set in tensor flow for a prediction model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I know that for training you model and see the accuracy you must use something like this:

```
print("Fit model on training data")
history = model.fit(
    X_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=64,
    epochs=2,
    validation_data=valid_set,
)
```

However,  I don't know how to put my own validation data set since it has a different length than my training data set and it has caused me many error along the way.
I even pre-processed my own validation dataset with the same process I used for my base dataset.
Any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: The size of validation dataset doesn't have to be the same as the training one. Can you show the specific errors you're getting?

Comment: ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [20575, 19508, 20575, 19508]

Comment: The size of your X and y data are different.

Comment: As mentioned by @pavel, Validation dataset's features column(input) and label column(output) dimensions must be equal to training dataset input and output column before proceeding for training the model which is causing the error. Please provide some more reproducible code along with traceback error to help you in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments , the shapes must match. However, in addition I would suggest you not to create a validation dataset separately.

From the original data, you can use the sklearn's train-test split to create your train and test data.

Again apply a train-test split on the train data to create your validation dataset.

You can as well use K-Fold cross validation on the existing dataset to achieve your goal.

Comment: You can use this [article](https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-perform-kfold-cross-validation-with-tensorflow/) to see How it is done in Neural Nets parlance.